# JSoup won't get the right date range for Google Search results

Tags: java, html, connection, jsoup, google-search

I've lurked on here for a while, but I officially joined today because I'm having a huge problem with JSoup. I'm creating a program in which I need to gather the small titles and descriptions that Google News gives when you search for a certain topic.

When I use this code:

(x.getURL() gives a google search page in news, from a certain date to another certain date)

```
    URLBuilder x = new URLBuilder(q, from.getMmddyyyy(), to.getMmddyyyy());

    String p = x.getURL();
    System.out.println(p);
    doc = Jsoup.connect(p).userAgent("Mozilla").get();
    System.out.println(doc);

    Elements links = doc.select("h3[class=_hJs");
    for (Element link : links) {
        Elements titles = link.select("a[class=l _PMs]");
        String title = titles.text();

        Elements bodies = link.select("div[class=st]");
        String body = bodies.text();

        System.out.println("Title: "+title);
        System.out.println("Body: "+body+"\n");
    }
```

The code works well, but the only problem is instead of giving me titles and bodies from the time I wanted, it gives me the html if you were to google my query right now in news. For example, my URL builder would give the URL (and also the URL that's printed in the output):

https://google.com/search?q=Apple+&tbm=nws&num=100&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A01%2F19%2F2016%2Ccd_max%3A01%2F23%2F2016

Which if you follow gives you a google search results for "Apple" with 100 results per page, from News, **from the dates 1/19/2016 to 1/23/2016 only.** However, when in the next line I print out the HTML doc, it gives the HTML from a google search results for "Apple" with 100 results per page, from News, **but from the current date.**

What's happening here? I've tried everything, but why won't JSoup give the HTML from that specific page??? I've tried all different types of .userAgents including not using that altogether but nothing with that has worked.

Seriously, if you even have an **inkling** of an idea for a solution please share it with me. I'll try anything, this thing has been killing me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works:

```java
package jhy;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;

public class NewsTest {
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        String url = "https://google.com/search?q=Apple+&tbm=nws&num=100&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A01%2F19%2F2016%2Ccd_max%3A01%2F23%2F2016";
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

        Elements links = doc.select("h3 a");
        for (String title : links.eachText()) {
            System.out.println(title);
        }
    }
}
```

And outputs:

```
Apple's First iOS App Development Center In Europe Will Be ...
Apple wins court order banning sale of old Samsung phones
Apple, Microsoft, Samsung Linked To Child Mining In DRC, Says ...
Apple Eyes Launching Stores In India
Apple Veteran Overseeing Electric-Car Project Leaving Company
```

Please make sure you're using the [latest version of jsoup](https://jsoup.org/download) (1.10.3 today). There was a bug in how redirects with %xx in the URL were handled in the previous version which may have impacted you.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to connect with Jsoup it shows the latest news. I don't know why it is happening, but you can reach that page with date range in browser. So you can use selenium to crawl that page here is how you can do it;

```
WebDriver driver = null;
    DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    cap.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, "C:\\Users\\PER\\Desktop\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\chrome.exe");
    cap.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_PAGE_CUSTOMHEADERS_PREFIX + "accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
    cap.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_PAGE_CUSTOMHEADERS_PREFIX + "accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch, br");
    cap.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_PAGE_CUSTOMHEADERS_PREFIX + "Accept-Language", "en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4");
    cap.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_PAGE_CUSTOMHEADERS_PREFIX + "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36");

    driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
    driver.navigate().to("https://google.com/search?q=Apple+&tbm=nws&num=100&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A01%2F19%2F2016%2Ccd_max%3A01%2F23%2F2016");;

    String doc = driver.getPageSource();
    Document document = Jsoup.parse(doc);
    System.out.println(doc);

    Elements links = document.select("h3[class=_hJs");
    for (Element link : links) {
        Elements titles = link.select("a[class=l _PMs]");
        String title = titles.text();

        Elements bodies = link.select("div[class=st]");
        String body = bodies.text();

        System.out.println("Title: "+title);
        System.out.println("Body: "+body+"\n");
    }
```

also you need to import these;

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
```